# pushViewController causing crash

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, ios6.1

I am using this code to push my next view controller, it was working fine with IOS 7, now I have changed the deployment target to 6.1. I am calling this code from tableview cell's didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Its causing a crash when the cell is tapped only the first time, afterward goes smooth. There is no crash log. It is still working fine on iOS 7.

```
UIViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Test"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

I tried setting "animated=NO" it works fine

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:NO];
```

Where is the problem?
 Also, I am setting cell's background color in cellForRowAtIndexPath, in iOS 7 shows the color but not in iOS 6.1

Comment: Where's the crash log?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
UIViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Test"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

with:

```
UIViewController *view =(UIViewController *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Test"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Comment: @AzkaarAli why not try to use - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
         to go to detailview, since you're using the storyboard?

Comment: In my case I am calling different View controllers from each cell. How can I draw a separate Segue for every call?

Comment: @AzkaarAli Why do not recall the same viewcontroller and it only changes the content? otherwise you could try connecting each cell to correct detail and the method I wrote above you could use this code:    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detail1"]) {} else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detail2"]) ...